# many PerformanceCounter not changing value

Tags: c#, performancecounter

Hi i create many PerformanceCounter
My problem is when i set value of one counter it change in all other counters
this is my code:

```
 public class PerformanceCounterHelper
{
    private const string COUNTER_STILL_ALIVE = "Nb secondes depuis dernière activité";
    private const string COUNTER_STILL_ALIVE_HELP = "Nombre de secondes depuis le dernier signe de vie";

    private const string COUNTER_MESSAGE_NUMBER = "Nb messages traités";
    private const string COUNTER_MESSAGE_NUMBER_HELP = "Nombre de messages traités par le dispatcher";

    private const string COUNTER_MESSAGE_ERROR = "Nb messages en erreur";
    private const string COUNTER_MESSAGE_ERROR_HELP = "Nombre de messages en erreur";

    private PerformanceCounter stillAliveCounter;
    private PerformanceCounter messageNumberCounter;
    private PerformanceCounter messageErrorNumberCounter;
    public PerformanceCounterHelper(string categoryName)
    {
        stillAliveCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, COUNTER_STILL_ALIVE, false);
        messageNumberCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, COUNTER_MESSAGE_NUMBER, false);
        messageErrorNumberCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, COUNTER_MESSAGE_ERROR, false);
        //DonnerSigneDeVie();

        messageNumberCounter.RawValue = 0;
        messageErrorNumberCounter.RawValue = 0;
    }
    public void DonnerSigneDeVie() {stillAliveCounter.RawValue = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();}

    public void IncrementerNombreMessagesTraites()
    {
        messageNumberCounter.RawValue += 1;
    }


    public void IncrementerNombreMessagesEnErreur()
    {
        messageErrorNumberCounter.RawValue += 1;
    }

    public PerformanceCounterHelper()
    { }
```

In the end all counters values have values  "3"

Comment: How have you declared RawValue?

Comment: no i dont  how i have to do it?

Comment: Look at my answer, show us the code of your class.

Comment: @Abdou Better if you show us a class PerformanceCounter first

Comment: i cant post an answer and i cant put it in comment because itis very long

Comment: You can edit your question..

Comment: "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: Look at my answer, you can see how you can edit your question..

Comment: Done i have modified the code on the top

Comment: You must show us the "PerformanceCounter" class and not the "PerformanceCounterHelper" class

Comment: PerformanceCounter is a metadata class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your class **PerformanceCounter**, but I think there is a static variable in it, that holds the `RawValue`!?

Remove the `static` from the variable and it should work.

---

For more feedback, please show us the class.

---

How to edit a question:

[image]

Comment: +one to your answer my bad!